# Internet Explorer 8 not letting one save .SWF's

Tags: download, internet-explorer-8, swf

Not ruling out this being be a GPO setting, but IE8 at my work doesn't seem to allow the download of .SWF's (As one example):

[image]

Does anyone know why / possible reasons?

Comment: Could be lots of reasons. What did you try to trouble shoot or more importantly, what have you ruled out? Does it work in other browsers?

Comment: @ser66001 - Talk to your IT staff about this, if its a group policy rule, there isn't much you can do about it.

Comment: @DaveRook - Works in Firefox/Chrome; All files on the first page of google.com/#q=filetype:swf have the same issue; It is a domain controlled environment, and my permissions limit what other troubleshooting I can do (Besides, I wouldn't be posting here if I could/wanted to approach internal sources), but have since [found evidence that GPO's cannot lock down file types allowed to be saved](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6d744492-2914-49e1-b45e-36b06149cac2/ie8-file-download-filtering-by-file-type-possible). Ramhound - I am in my companies IT dept.

Answer (score 0):

Most web sites store Flash animations and movies on your hard drive as temporary Internet files. If you know where to find these files, you can copy and paste them to another folder easily.

Open Internet Explorer and browse to the site that has the Flash .SWF file you want to download.

Allow the animation, game or movie to load in Internet Explorer. This may take several minutes, but allow the file to load completely before continuing.

Click "Tools" on the menu bar and then "Internet Options."

Click the "General" tab in the "Internet Options" window, then click the "Settings" button under the "Browsing history" header. Click the "View files" button in the "Settings" dialog-box window.

Scroll through the list of temporary Internet files until you come to the .SWF file you want to download. Right click on the file and then click the "Copy" option on the pop-up menu.

Click "Start" and then "Computer" or "My Computer." Browse to the folder where you want to save the .SWF file and open it.

Right click in the open space of the folder window and then click the "Paste" option. Windows will copy the .SWF file into the folder.